# Is there a way to wrap function calls in a decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my flask application, I interact with MongoDB. For resilience, I follow a pattern to wrap the insert/update operations in a retry loop like this -

```
retry = 3
while (retry>0):
    try:
        response = db.collection_name.insert({'name' : 'somename'})
        if response: #or something relevant to the query.
          #do something
          break
        else:
          #do something else
          break
    except:
        retry-=1
```

This is a pattern I find myself using for almost all the update/insert operations. Now, I was wondering if there is a way to avoid writing the same loop again and again.

While looking how we can write decorators to decouple an action and apply it on any function we want ex. timing a function run, I wondered if it is possible to do something similar for db calls (or a specific set or instruction) without putting them in a function.

Comment: Why not wrap the pattern into a regular function and call that, supplying just the moving parts as parameters?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What part of the pattern is where the wrapped function would get called?

Comment: I'm confused; isn't it the database's job to ensure the operation completes if possible?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I thought of that but that would mean defining a function for all the commands available separately. Would work but it doesn't sit right with me.

Comment: @martineau it should ideally replace the while block that I have mentioned here.

Comment: @kaya3 True when the command reaches the database. In horizontally scalable database (having replica sets and multi-shard) clusters, I have seen db calls failing during leader selection process. Although, there is a server selection timeout exception available and we can simply get away by catching this exception an try again but I like to keep it this way for some bizzare issues that I haven't come across yet.

Comment: @ShubhamS Of course this depends on details which aren’t available but what I meant was that you only define *one* such wrapper function that’s usable for all actions.

Comment: ShubhamS: Decorators are applied to a function and return a modified one that typically calls the original at some point. So what I want to know is, if this hypothetical decorator was applied to function `my_func()` where would the call to that be in the snippet of code in your question?

Comment: @martineau the call should ideally replace the snippet.
Also, what I want to know is if there's a way to actually decorate specific code without putting them in a function. This should be very useful because most of the software development is api driven. It isn't always possible to go decorate the definition of that function. So, I was hoping to find a way to decorate the function call itself.

Comment: No, you can't decorate the calls to the functions themselves. Decorators are just "syntactic-sugar" and are equivalent to having a `my_func = my_decorator(my_func)` _following_ the definition of `my_func()` instead of putting `@my_decorator` on a line immediately _before_ its definition.

Comment: Alright. I think what @KonradRudolph suggested would be the best option here then.

Comment: You may want to try existing libraries like [retry](https://pypi.org/project/retry/) or [retry-decorator](https://pypi.org/project/retry-decorator/).

Comment: @PaulRooney hey thanks for the suggestion. Checked the library. It doesn't solve what I was hoping for here but it's pretty neat and would be very helpful. Thank mate.

Comment: I came up with [this](https://ideone.com/8M1nai) not sure if it helps?